# Remove session from browser cache in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, browser-cache

I am using angular js as front end and Java as backend. I need to invalidate the session when the use closes the tab irrespective of the session. Whenever he hits the url, he need to be redirected to the login page.

I have tried including the following in index.html

```
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Also in the js side,

```
   app.run(function($templateCache) {
 $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
     $templateCache.removeAll();
 });
});
 app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      $templateCache.removeAll();
   });
});
```

Can anyone suggest me what to furthur for this.

Need to handle this in IE also.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, clear the session in the first controller invoked. Later add a condition in the statechange that if session is empty goto login page. `$window.sessionStorage.clear(); $window.localStorage.clear();`

Comment: If there are many tabs open, should invalidate the session once one of the tabs is closed?

Comment: is this enough?

Comment: Alexis Toby, its not working.

Comment: Jin, only one tab will be opened at once. have to invalidate session if that tab is closed.